# If $\lim_{i \to \infty} x_i = L$, $\lim_{i \to \infty} y_i =\infty$, is $\lim_{i \to \infty}x_i y_i = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits

If $\lim_{i \to \infty} x_i = L$  withh $L>0$ and finite real and $\lim_{i \to \infty} y_i =\infty$, is $\lim_{i \to \infty}x_i y_i = \infty$? How can one prove this?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon =L/2$, there exsit $N$ such that $x_i>L-\varepsilon =L/2$ for all $i>N$.

Also for any $M>0$, there exsit $N'$ such that $y_j>\frac{2M}{L}$ for all $j>N'$.

Then we have $x_ky_k>M$ for all $k>max\{N,N'\}$.

And that's $\lim_{i \to \infty}x_i y_i = \infty$.